# How to load submodule dynamically

Tags: python

I setup this complex structure to load submodules dynamically:

```
Main.py
src \ Clean.py
Source \ Amazon \ Clean.py
Source \ Google \ Clean.py
Source \ Amazon \ __init__.py
Source \ Google \ __init__.py
```

My src \ Clean.py look like this:

```
import importlib
Vendors = ["Amazon","Google"]
def Run(Config):
    results = ""
    for vendor in Vendors:
        mod = importlib.import_module("source."+vendor)
        results += mod.Run()
    return results
```

My __init__.py look like this:

```
__all__ = ["clean"]
```

My source>>amazon>>clean.py look like this:

```
def Run():
    return "Amazon Clean Test"
```

When I call src \ clean.py, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'source.Amazon' has no attribute 'Run'
```

I am calling the whole thing in Main.py:

```
import src.clean as Clean
result = Clean.Run(Config)
```

I guess it couldn't load the module in source \ amazon \ clean.py?  How do I load that?

Stacktrace:

```
File "main.py", line 2, in clean
  result = Clean.Run(Config)
File "src\clean.py", line 7, in Run
  results += mod.Run()
AttributeError: module 'source.Amazon' has no attribute 'Run'
```

Comment: What does `>>` mean? I don't see any function calls, what's in `clean.py` or which part could yield the error. Can you include the traceback of the error?

Comment: sorry it's just my way of writing sub folder, I'll change it to \

Comment: It's just a test to make sure this work, I haven't wrote any code to do work yet, I have included the entire __init__.py please specify how I should fix it.

Comment: Actually I got it to work will post answer soon

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work!

In src \ clean.py, change it dynamic import line to this:

```
    mod = importlib.import_module("source."+vendor+".clean")
```

Delete __init__.py

That's it!